# VIM Rubocop Ruby duplication of prompts/comments after each row of code

Tags: ruby, vim, rubocop

[image]

It is default rubocop comments in each file after each row where there is rubocop issue. I have such rubocop behaviour for last three monthes and have no idea how to avoid comments like this.
(please, look at the image above)
In my `.vimrv` file I have plagin

```
ngmy/vim-rubocop
```

and couple directions

```
let g:vimrubocop_config = '/path/to/rubocop.yml'
let g:syntastic_ruby_checkers = ['rubocop']
```

rubocop.yml

```
#require: rubocop-rspec

AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.6

  # additional excludes for Rails
  Exclude:
    - 'db/migrate/**/*'
    - 'db/schema.rb'
    - 'db/seeds.rb'
    - 'db/migrate/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'bin/**/*'
    - 'log'
    - 'public/**/*'
    - 'tmp/**/*'
    - 'vendor/**/*'

Lint/RaiseException:
  Enabled: true

Lint/StructNewOverride:
  Enabled: true

Style/HashEachMethods:
  Enabled: true

Style/HashTransformKeys:
  Enabled: true

Style/HashTransformValues:
  Enabled: true

Layout/LineLength:
  Max: 120
  IgnoredPatterns: ['\A#']

Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 20

Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 15

Metrics/ClassLength:
  Max: 120

Metrics/BlockLength:
  Max: 30

Layout/SpaceInLambdaLiteral:
  EnforcedStyle: require_space

Style/StringLiterals:
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes

Style/Documentation:
  Enabled: false
```

How to avoid these comments?
Tanks a lot

I tried to modify my vimrc, comment all directions related to rubocop settings

Answer (score 0):

Those messages are from [Reek](https://github.com/troessner/reek), not RuboCop.

Comment: Andy) Thank you very very much))) You are definitely right!  And your advise saved me) I never faced with Reek gem and never installed it but my project has Ruby critic gem wich has dependens with Reek under the hood. I uninstalled Reek from local machine and everything were returned back)))

Comment: Hi Andy! I opened my project on new mac and what I see))) I see my old friends, rubocop comments  after each row on screen)) I have only set up vimrc, nothing more, even  did not bundle install))) no one gem was not installed on mac))